# Create Word/RTF file with table of contents from Java

Tags: java, ms-word

I want to create a Word or RTF file with a table of contents (with links to each section) from Java. From my understanding, iText & Apache POI do not support generating a table of contents. Some clients of the app still use older versions of Word, so I need a library that supports the older Word doc format. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks,

Glen

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [Java API for OpenOffice](http://api.openoffice.org/). It will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but possibly helpful to others.  [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) is a good option here.  It works over the OpenOffice API but you don't have to spend the time learning that API.  It provides template population and manipulation, a range of data source options and all the input and output options of OpenOffice.  Specifically, it also updates the TOC and indexes at the final stages of document rendering.